# Square root of two positive integers less than or equal to the sum of both integers direct proof

Tags: number-theory, inequality, square-numbers

Please help with this problem.

If x and y positive integers, show:
$$2\sqrt{xy} \le x + y $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a standard $AM-GM$ inequality and it can be proved in many ways and here's a one kind of approach:

> Result: If $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$ are positive numbers and  $a_1\cdots a_n=1$ then $$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n \geq n$$

Take $$a_1=\frac{x}{\sqrt{xy}}$$ and $$a_2=\frac{y}{\sqrt{xy}}$$ and apply above result to see $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{xy}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{xy}} \geq 2\Rightarrow \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{xy}} \ge 2 \Rightarrow x+y \geq2 \sqrt{xy}$$

Comment: I understand this even though I have never been exposed to AM-GM inequality principle before

Comment: Actually the mentioned result is easy to prove by induction

Comment: Well they said by direct proof so they don't really want induction which we are just starting. But I can clearly see what you did with the principle.

Comment: anyway you understand whats going  on here! that s ok!

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})^2 = x - 2\sqrt{xy} + y \geq 0$.

> **Rationale:**  For any real numbers a,b, $(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2 \geq 0 \implies a^2 + b^2 \geq 2ab$.  Since $x, y > 0$, $\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{y}$ are real numbers.  Thus, if we set $a = \sqrt{x}$ and $b =\sqrt{y}$, we obtain $$(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})^2 = x - 2\sqrt{xy} + y \geq 0 \iff x + y \geq 2\sqrt{xy}$$

Comment: What principle did you apply to get the left-hand side

Comment: The idea here is that $(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2 \geq 0 \implies a^2 + b^2 \geq 2ab$.  Since $x$ and $y$ are positive, $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{y}$ exist, so I set $a = \sqrt{x}$ and $b = \sqrt{y}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x$ and $y$ are positive.

Your question is equivalent to $G.M\le A.M$.

$GM$ means geometric mean and $AM$ means arithmetic mean of $x&y$.

Comment: Oi! how are you?

Comment: 8489827386 WhatsApp va oi

Comment: Nan call panren oi... In college...

Comment: ok! call me whenever you are free!